# Specifying Paths for exporting files in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am writing my first own Coq file but I am experiencing trouble in exporting another user defined file (defined by the book Software Foundations).

The issue is my current Coq file has path `Coq/NWA.v` and the file I want to import has path `Coq/SoftwareFoundations/lf/Rel.v`. I tried the following syntaxes:

```
From Coq/SoftwareFoundations/lf Require Import Rel.v
```

&

```
From Coq.SoftwareFoundations.lf Require Import Rel.v
```

&

```
From ./../SoftwareFoundations/lf Require Import Rel.v
```

all of which give a syntax error. How can I import the Rel.v file?

Comment: It might be relevant to read the first section of https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Induction.html

Comment: I followed the steps: 
(1) I made a _CoqProject file with content '-Q ./../SoftwareFoundations/lf/ LF' .
(2) I added the line From 'LF Require Export Rel' in my file NWA.v.
(3) From command line I run the cmd: "coq_makefile -f _CoqProject *.v -o Makefile"
(4) I recompiled the file Rel.v
I still got a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: The correct syntax is

```
From LF Require Import Rel.
```

---

To manage Coq files, there are two kinds of paths to be aware of:

- Physical paths: the usual file paths you're used to, like `Coq/SoftwareFoundations/lf`.
- Logical paths: fully qualified module names, that are mapped to files by the Coq compiler.

What the `-Q my/path/to/lf LF` option (that ultimately needs to be passed to `coqc`) does is map logical paths (`LF`) to physical paths (`my/path/to/lf`).

In a Coq file, the `Require Import` command (including the `From _ Require Import _`) works with logical paths. The rule of thumb is that the contents of a `.v` file only talks about logical paths, although there are a couple of exceptions (e.g., `Add LoadPath` and extraction).

The Logical Foundations volume is built using logical path `LF.ModuleName`, that's what you need to use in `Coq/NWA.v` to import `Rel`:

```
From LF Require Import Rel.

(* or *)

Require Import LF.Rel.
```

Comment: How is the -Q my/path/to/lf LF option passed to coqc ?

Comment: To pass the -Q my/path/to/lf LF option to coqc, I ran the following command in terminal: coq_makefile -f _CoqProject *.v -o Makefile
But I get the following error:

Warning: ..\SoftwareFoundations\lf\ (used in -R or -Q) is not a subdirectory of the current directory


Warning: no common logical root

Warning: in such case INSTALLDEFAULTROOT must be defined

Warning: the install-doc target is going to install files

Warning: in orphan_LF_Top

Comment: Those warnings are expected if your physical path contains `..`. It's okay to ignore those warnings.